# Thread-safe queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue

This is what I have which is mostly based on code I've found on Stack Overflow. How good is it? Can you suggest better implementation?

```
#pragma once

#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <deque>

template <typename T>
class BlockingQueue
{
private:
    std::mutex              d_mutex;
    std::condition_variable d_condition;
    std::deque<T>           d_queue;
public:
    void push(T const& value) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
            d_queue.push_front(value);
        }
        this->d_condition.notify_one();
    }
    T pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
        this->d_condition.wait(lock, [=]{ return !this->d_queue.empty(); });
        T rc(std::move(this->d_queue.back()));
        this->d_queue.pop_back();
        return rc;
    }
    bool tryPop (T & v, std::chrono::milliseconds dur) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->d_mutex);
        if (!this->d_condition.wait_for(lock, dur, [=]{ return !this->d_queue.empty(); })) {
            return false;
        }
        v = std::move (this->d_queue.back());
        this->d_queue.pop_back();
        return true;
    }
    int size() {
        return d_queue.size();
    }
};
```

Comment: i completely replaced this queue with two - boost spsc and tbb concurrent_bounded_queue.

Answer (score 11):

Overall the code looks functional to me. Everytime you pop it will wait on the condition variable if the queue is empty. Everytime you push, a notification will be sent to any thread waiting in the pop method because the queue is empty and let it know that the queue is not empty anymore. I can't speak for your intentions but that is generally how people want their queues to work.

A few minor points I noticed:

The std::move in this line is useless since deque::back() will give you an rvalue anyway.

```
 std::move (this->d_queue.back());
```

It looks like someone on SO trying to look clever not actually understanding the code.

This will suffice.

```
v = this->d_queue.back();
```

In the lambda functions, capturing everything by value is completely unnecessary.

```
[=]{ return !this->d_queue.empty(); }
```

Capture only the this pointer or only the deque by reference.

```
[this]{ return !this->d_queue.empty(); }

[&d_queue]{ return !d_queue.empty(); }
```

Both approaches have the same overhead.

Comment: But isn't won't the compiler be smart enough to capture only the variables that are used?

Comment: It seems this is pretty much [code I posted to stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12805690/1120273), i.e., I'm the person who "wants to look clever not actually understanding the code" (the _insulted_ for short). Incidentally, `std::deque<...>::back()` returns a `reference` not a `value_type` according to 23.3.3.1 [deque.overview] paragraph 2. Thus, your reasoning is wrong and your code change actually doesn't work as `std::unique_ptr<T>` doesn't have a copy assignment. You might want to check your facts before making smug comments.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, your point about unique_ptr is incorrect, because of how BlockingQueue::push implemented. It will not accept unique_ptr anyway. But part about move is ok.

Answer (score 6):

What @user2675345 said.

Also don't force a `std::deque` on your users. There is already a concept of a queue in C++. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/ Use the same technique and default to `std::deque` but allow other types.

```
template <typename T, Container = std::deque<T>>
class BlockingQueue
{
private:
    std::mutex              d_mutex;
    std::condition_variable d_condition;
    Container               d_queue;
```

It might be useful to support the same API as a `std::queue`

Answer (score 5):

I think you should also lock the `size()` function. The return type should also be `size_t` (or even `deque<T>::size_type`).